# Scaffolding for Django and AngularJS project?

Tags: angularjs, django

When you create a project and apps with Django, the Django engine creates the initial structure.

But when creating a project that runs Django and AngularJS on the same server, what structure do you recommend and why?

Comment: Isn't this primarily opinion based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At first avoid this kind of question here in Stackoverflow because it's just primairly opinion-based. Check [Stackoverflow Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to better understand the rules.**

When it's about code structure, you can find like the best answer since the structure it depends of many factors (project size, team work, developer background etc). I worken on some projects using Django, Django Rest Framework and AngularJS and end up with:

1. if the Angular app is small app it's more convinient to follow django structure so html files in `TEMPLATES` and js files in `STATIC`
2. if the Angular app is more complex on term of structure, it's better to have separate App so you make both your client and server side more maintainable and in this case I will recommand [Cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) as structure for Django; it's one of the most used structure and for AngularJS I will recommend the famous [Angular Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).

Make sure you take the right choice ;)